# using EMScripten with React Native

Tags: react-native, emscripten

I have compiled a c code to js code using EMScripten using this command in command prompt:

```
emcc [xxx.c] -o [xxx.js] -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['function1']"
```

and when I import Module from xxx.js within my index.js file, Module object is empty. Not sure if I need to change something within the generated file or if I did something wrong..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import Module from './xxx';

console.log(Module) // gives me {}
```

any suggestion will be appreciated.
thanks :)

Comment: Does addition of the string 'export default Module' (without quotes) at the end of xxx.js file help?

Answer (score 0):

Before you import your emscripten js file, you will need to create a "Module" object and implement a property(function) "onRuntimeInitialized".

Only after you get a callback on this function you can expect the Module object to be non-empty.

```
window.Module = {
    onRuntimeInitialized : function() {
        console.log("Emscripten Ready!");
        var event = new Event('emReady');
        // Dispatch the event.
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
};

// Now register for this event in your React code and only call Module functions when this event has been received.
```

Comment: The question that was asked was about React Native, not React. There is no `document` in React Native.

Comment: There should be some corresponding class/method to dispatch events.

Comment: @ChrisPoe I guess the idea is to show that the `Module` should be initialized first, before use. 
@TarunGehlaut _Before you import your emscripten js file_ - maybe we first actually import the file, and then implement the `Module`'s `onRuntimeInitialized()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and found an `emcc` option that solved it: `-s MODULARIZE=1`

MODULARIZE puts all the output into a function so when you call `Module`, you can call it as a function (`Module()`) and not receive an empty object.

For more details, here is a link to a more in-depth answer of mine:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54117913/4848700