# How to use Emscripten compiled JavaScript within React / React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, emscripten

I'm currently using Emscripten to compile a basic C function into JavaScript to use within a React Native project. However, when I import `Module` from inside React code, the Module object is empty. This occurs in both React and React Native projects.

**Running `index.js` in my terminal with `node ./index.js` returns the expected result.**

I'm compiling ping.c and outputting ping.js with this command:

`emcc ping.c -o ping.js -s WASM=0 -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='["_pingIt"]'`

**ping.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
int pingIt() {
  return 1;
}
```

**index.js:**

```
let Module = require('./ping.js');

module.exports = Module;
```

I'm exporting Module from `index.js` and importing it into my React code.

## Current behavior

```
// Running in React
console.log(Module); // returns {}
```

## Expected behavior

```
// Running in React
console.log(Module._pingIt()); // should return 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure if WASM supports ES6 import syntax yet. Have you tried adding a `script` tag in your `index.html` page and accessing `Module` as a global variable?

Comment: @seanulus my main goal is to get it to run inside a React Native project. I have disabled WASM with the `WASM=0` option in my `emcc` command.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I stumbled across a `MODULARIZE` setting in the Emscripten docs [here](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html#emcc-closure). I edited the `emcc` command:

```
emcc ping.c -o ping.js -s WASM=0 -s ENVIRONMENT=web -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["cwrap"]' -s MODULARIZE=1
```

`MODULARIZE=1` being the magic bit

Now within the `index.js` file:

```
let Module = require('./ping.js'); // Your Emscripten JS output file
let pingIt = Module().cwrap('pingIt'); // Call Module as a function

module.exports = pingIt;
```

Now in the React component you can `import pingIt from '<file-location>';` and call the function like any other `pingIt()`.

Hope someone finds this useful! I couldn't find many examples of using Emscripten alongside React.

Answer (score 1):

I used a slightly different approach to call the ping.c function from React Native, by defining an `EXPORT_NAME` for the module and creating the module whenever it's appropriate in your code.

Using Emscripten emsdk:

```
emcc ping.c -o ping.js -s WASM=0 -s ENVIRONMENT=web -s MODULARIZE=1 -s "EXPORT_NAME='createPingModule'"
```

In the React Native component (App.tsx):

```
import createPingModule from './ping';

...

createPingModule()
  .then(module => {
    console.log('Module created!');
    let a = module._pingIt();
    console.log(a);
});
```