# How to Use Emscripten JavaScript File in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, emscripten

I'm trying to import a JavaScript file into React that was compiled from C code using Emscripten. This is similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54115783/how-to-use-emscripten-compiled-javascript-within-react-react-native/54117913#54117913) but the answer does not seem to work. The goal is to be able to import the function in the JS file and call it as you would a named function. I compiled the JS file with `MODULARIZE=1` and `WASM=0` with the following command:

```
emcc ../../helloWorld/ping.c -o ../../helloWorld/ping.js -s WASM=0 -s ENVIRONMENT=web -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS="['cwrap']" -s MODULARIZE=1
```

ping.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
int pingIt() {
  return 1;
}
```

importPingIt.js

```
let Module = require('./ping.js'); // Your Emscripten JS output file
let pingIt = Module().cwrap('pingIt'); // Call Module as a function

Module.exports = pingIt;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import pingIt from './importPingIt.js';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  handleClick = () => {
    console.log("button clicked OK");
    pingIt();
  }

  render() {

    return (

      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}> Button 1 </button>
      </div>

    );
  }

}
```

When I compile, I get the following errors:

```
index.js:1375 ./src/ping.js
  Line 87:    Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 695:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 744:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 836:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 1009:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 1233:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 1487:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2133:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2271:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2284:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2302:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2585:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 2743:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 4006:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 4640:  'define' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 4641:   Expected imports instead of AMD define()                               import/no-amd
  Line 4641:   'define' is not defined                                                no-undef
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use some kind of asynchronous pattern to wait for the Wasm module to load.  Try something like this, which uses the `pingIt.ready` Promise:

```
import pingItWasm from './importPingIt.js';

let pingIt = {
  ready: new Promise(resolve => {
    pingItWasm({
      onRuntimeInitialized() {
        pingIt = this.pingIt;
        pingIt.ready = Promise.resolve()
        resolve();
      }
    });
  })
};

(async () {
  await pingIt.ready;
  pingIt();
})()
```